# Can I use WD My Passport locked drive to boot directly as USB drive?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

My question is regarding WD My Passport Ultra 2GB. I have locked my drive with secure password. But Can I use that drive to boot my laptop directly from USB port ?

My Lenovo Thinkpad E440 laptop supports Harddisk encryption from its bios settings.

Comment: Manufacturer documentation doesn't mention anything about boot. It mentiones all locking features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, I have tested with my Lenovo ThinkPad E440 with locked harddisk. But it didn't boot directly from BIOS. Hence, seems that laptop bios supports harddisk password only when directly connected to SATA.

Answer (score 0):

A quick read of the Lenovo website regarding Full Disk Encryption (FDE) states that it is only SATA drives that can be encrypted using the BIOS utility.

It seems that an encrypted USB disk can only be used within the OS (BitLocker etc.).